# how to use DELETE AND PUT command in CURL php?

Tags: php, curl, quickblox

I am sending a DELETE request to Quick blox API for custom object class. but its not deleting the record. I am using CURL php to send the request.
here is my code:

```
$url =" https://api.quickblox.com/data/TopPlace/50e3d8db535c123833015181.json" 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

But after executing this command its not delete data. I echo $status its shows me 422 code.

Comment: can you show us what your `$data` is

Comment: my data is :
$data = placename=london&total=2
I have created a custom object class in quickblox admin panel.
placename and total is the custom variable name in that class.

Comment: The examples at http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects say you need to include QB-Token

Comment: yes i am passing qb-token as well :

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("QB-Token: $token"));

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a 422 Status Code. Did you look that up?

[Quoting from Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. These status codes are applicable to any request method. User agents should display any included entity to the user.

And for 422 in particular:

> 422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918): The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.

[RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) gives more details:

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

So the answer is likely that the content of your `$data` is not what the server expects.

Also make sure to check the [documentation for Possible API Error Codes in that QuickBlox API](http://quickblox.com/developers/Errors#Errors_Unprocessable_Entity):

- http://quickblox.com/developers/Errors#Errors_Unprocessable_Entity

Since you state the error is

```
{"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}
```

my naive assumption is you forgot to authenticate before using the service.

Comment: i m getting error from quick blox reponse :
{"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}

Comment: @hitender so? add a user to your $data.

Comment: i have authenticate before sending the data. I got session token and i m passing token in the request as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use QuickBlox APIs you must create session. Then you will have READ access in QuickBlox environment.

In order to CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE records you must be logged in and to act on user behalf.

So, there are 2 ways:

- [create session with user's parameters](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#With_User_authorization)
- create session and then [sign in](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_User_Sign_In)

Also, be aware that you be able to delete own object, not other user's object.

Comment: thank a lot! you are right, we need to login User API (http://api.quickblox.com/login.json) to upgrade his session from API Application level to API User level which then allow to delete and create data. 
I now solved my problem and able to delete and create data.
Thanks a lot again!
i now close it.